# Multiple viewport resizing

Tags: rendering, viewport, rendertexture, rendertargets

I wonder how multiple viewports are handled in engines in terms of render targets buffers. Especially in the case of their resizing (for example changing the size of windows/viewports in Editor dock systems).

We apparently need separate color and depth buffers for each, and the sizes of these buffers should be equal to the sizes of viewports.

So does it means, that we have to recreate those buffers each time we resize viewports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little digging found out that it can be enough to have only one main color (backbuffer) and depth buffer.
For proper rendering and clearing buffers between different viewports we can just use scissors test setting scissors equal to each viewport we about to draw. 
So theres no need to additional handle "virtual" viewports changes and resize buffers, just set new values for scissors rect

Metal API case:
You can't simply set scissors and only after that clean the render target in metal api. It's should be in vice versa.
So I managed it by creating additional pass that only draws clear color on provided viewport size. It runs before any other passes each time we meet new viewport during frame rendering.
[image]

Comment: If this answered your question, be sure to click the checkmark in the top-left corner to mark this answer as Accepted.